# what are different types of sessions in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session

Here I want to know different types of Session in ASP.NET and not Session States. That was the question asked in an interview.

Comment: Just to be clear.  The correct answer is not "InMemory", "SQLServer" and "StateService"?

Comment: No that are the Session Storage or Session States. I need to know Session Types..

Comment: please find more details about session in below link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net#2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typical sessions are based on a cookie. The server gives you one, you send it to the server upon every request. However, Asp.net allows you a different type of sessions as well - cookieless sessions. The session id is then "stored" in the URL address. This technique is very dangerous if used improperly.

Answer (score 21):

Session-State modes are 5 type:

**InProc mode:** which stores session state in memory on the Web server. This is the default.

**StateServer mode:** which stores session state in a separate process called the ASP.NET state service. This ensures that session state is preserved if the Web application is restarted and also makes session state available to multiple Web servers in a Web farm.

**SQLServer** mode stores session state in a SQL Server database. This ensures that session state is preserved if the Web application is restarted and also makes session state available to multiple Web servers in a Web farm.

**Custom mode:** which enables you to specify a custom storage provider.

**Off mode:** which disables session state.

Check the detail. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

Comment: This answer is better than the accepted answer because it gives explanation of each type.

Comment: @AkshayRaut Fully Agreed!

Answer (score 3):

Would definitely need more clarification from the OP. I feel the terms are being used inter-changeably.

By nature web is state-less. To overcome this ASP.Net provides several state management options like viewstate, controlstate etc. Session State is one of these options.

ASP.NET **session state** supports several **storage options** for session variables. Each option is identified as a session-state **mode** type. There are four **mode types** or just **modes**. In-Process mode, State Server mode, SQL Server mode, Custom mode and Off mode. These are **modes**. In-Process mode uses memory as **session storage**. State Server mode uses state-server as **session storage**. And so on. Besides, when a mode is specified by way of web.config, some additional parameters are also required like connectionstring, timeout etc. One of these parameters is "cookieless" for which the default value is "AutoDetect". If specified as "true", it will embed the ID in url. (As explained by @naivists). Cookieless option can be used with any mode.

This is all what there is to ASP.Net Session. I feel there is just some confusion on terms state, mode, mode type, storage etc. being used interchangeably. Apart from that there should be no other separate thing as "session type".

Answer (score 2):

There are three kinds of session, and they are listed as follows

1. Inprocess.
2. Outprocess.
3. Sql server session.

where they are stored.

1. inproc - default stored in web.config.
2. outproc - stored in server side.
3. Sql server - stored in database.

You have following types of session management in asp.net which you can define in your web.config file

Session mode="inproc"...means the session will be stored on the webserver within your application
session mode="outproc"....means session will be stored on the server outside your application
session mode="stateserver"...means session will be stored in a temporary memory in the database
session mode="sqlserver"...means session will be stored in the database permanently.

Answer (score 0):

three types of session in asp.net.

- inprocess session
- out Process session
- SQl-server session

Comment: That's session *storage*. Apparently (see comments on question) the OP wants something else.